# From Goodfellow book: why can one rescale argmax of conditional probability into an expectation?

Tags: conditional-probability, machine-learning

I don't understand why the two equations below are equivalent.

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{\rm ML} &= \mathop{\rm argmax}_\boldsymbol{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log p_{\rm model}(\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}; \boldsymbol{\theta}) \tag{5.58}\label{5.58} \\
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{\rm ML} &= \mathop{\rm argmax}_\boldsymbol{\theta} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x} \sim \hat{p}_{\rm data}} \log p_{\rm model}(\boldsymbol{x}; \boldsymbol{\theta}) \tag{5.59}\label{5.59}
\end{align}

Quoted from [chapter 5 of *Deep Learning*](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html):

> Because the $\mathop{\rm argmax}$ does not change when we rescale the cost function, we can divide by $m$ to obtain a version of the criterion that is expressed as an expectation with respect to the empirical distribution $\hat{p}_{\rm data}$ deﬁned by the training data.

Comment: I've tried to edit your post to fix the typo.  Plz check if I've altered the context.  A technical note for Edge users at the bottom of [the book's website](https://www.deeplearningbook.org): "Known issues: In outdated versions of the Edge browser, the "does not equal" sign sometimes appears as the "equals" sign. This may be resolved by updating to the latest version."

Comment: Thanks. You didn't alter the context. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I did removed the $\hat{p}_{\rm data}$.  I've read the relevant paragraphs, and I've tried to improve the $\rm\LaTeX$ so that it's styled identically with the original work.  I'm going to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just takes a bit of time to find out where the symbols are defined.  There's no computations involved in this question.
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{\rm ML} &= \mathop{\rm argmax}_\boldsymbol{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log p_{\rm model}(\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}; \boldsymbol{\theta}) \tag{5.58}\label{558} \\
&= \mathop{\rm argmax}_\boldsymbol{\theta} \underbrace{\frac1m}_\text{const.} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \log p_{\rm model}(\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}; \boldsymbol{\theta}) \tag{divide by $m$}\label{frac1m}
\end{align}

In \eqref{559}, $\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}$'s are replaced by $\boldsymbol{x}$, and a new symbol $\hat{p}_{\rm data}$ is introduced, so it's better to scroll up the page to see where they are defined.

> Consider a set of $m$ examples $\mathbb{X} = \{\boldsymbol{x}^{(1)}, \dots, \boldsymbol{x}^{(m)}\}$ drawn independently from the true but unknown data-generating distribution $\hat{p}_{\rm data}(\mathbf{x})$.

Observe the difference in **boldface *styles*** and their corresponding meaning.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{$\rm \LaTeX$ code} & \texttt{\boldsymbol{x}} & \texttt{\mathbf{x}} \\ \hline
\text{output} & \boldsymbol{x} & \mathbf{x} \\ \hline
\text{meaning} & \text{realized} & \text{theoretical} \\ \hline
\text{usage} & \boldsymbol{x}^{(i)} & \hat{p}_{\rm data}(\mathbf{x}) \\ \hline
\end{array}

Let's take a closer look at the ${\rm \small{\bf smaller}}$ part of \eqref{559}

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{\rm ML} = \mathop{\rm argmax}_\boldsymbol{\theta} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x} \sim \hat{p}_{\rm data}} \log p_{\rm model}(\boldsymbol{x}; \boldsymbol{\theta}). \tag{5.59}\label{559}
\end{equation}

It reads

$${\huge \mathbf{x} \sim \hat{p}_{\rm data}}. \tag{subscript} \label{sub}$$

From the previous quoted text, it's clear that $\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}$'s are i.i.d. with (unknown) distribution $\hat{p}_{\rm data}$.  In \eqref{558}, we calculate $\log p_{\rm model}(\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}; \boldsymbol{\theta})$ from these $m$ realisations $\boldsymbol{x}^{(i)}$'s with $i = 1,\dots, m$, then we take the simple average in \eqref{frac1m}.  The symbol $\mathbb{E}$ captures the idea of "average" and the \eqref{sub} indicates the underlying probability distribution.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I was confused by the notation, but you cleared it up.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, please [consider "accept" the answer](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/290189) by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](//math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).